# After LatexMk upgrade commands does not work

Tags: mac, latexmk

I'm a OSX user with [BasicTex](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/basictex.rb) installed trough Homebrew.

When I used a version tagged like **Tex Live 2015** and I had installed LatexMk with had the following binary `latexmk`.

With this I was able to run `latexmk -C` and `latexmk -pdf -g random.tex`.

Now that I have installed the latest version of **Tex Live 2016** and installed LatexMk and new binary is available, `latex-mk`

And the previous command does not work with the new binary.

I have looked into the help pages of `latex-mk` but did not found which are the new parameters to substitute for.

Any advice?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `latex-mk` is a different beast than `latexmk`.

Comment: @piet-van-oostrum I understand that the latest version was upgraded, but there is no backward compatibility?

I was wondering if the new version allows to reproduce those tasks but with a new "syntax" (aka parameters).

Comment: No, it is a completely different thing. Try to find `latexmk`. It is part of TeXlive-2016.

Comment: Oh, after the upgrade I did not found the `latexmk`, so after looking I found `latex-mk` and thought they were the same. I was wrong, but I did thought that disruptive changes were a strange thing. Anyway, thanks, I will try it to find it.

Comment: Try if you can get it with `sudo tlmgr install latexmk`

Comment: @piet-van-oostrum you are right! after installing `latexmk` with `tlmgr` these commands worked perfectly as supposed.

Thanks, if you want you can put your advice as an answer and I will validate it as "correct" and you will gain the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with running in Terminal

```
sudo tlmgr install latexmk
```